# How to take screenshot with transparent windows WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

I need your help please.

I want to take a screenshot of all my screens except for the app screen, the app screen background is transparent but I don't want my elemnts in the screen shot.

The current code that I am using is:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth), Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight));
System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bm);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
```

I am writing in WPF.

Thatnk's for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to hide your window, take the screenshot, then show it again.

Comment: I can't hide my window, I need to make a movie of my screen without the app window. I f I would do like you suggest me i't doesn't look good.